# Sorting ArrayList of Maps based on a map value

Tags: sorting, arraylist, groovy

Let's say I have this `ArrayList` of `Map`s

```
def map1 = [key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3]
def map2 = [key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3]
def map3 = [key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3]
def maps = [map1, map2, map3]
```

I want to sort this list based on `value3` of the map.

How can I do that assuming that I'm working in Groovy?

Comment: Why do you not use simple http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator) ?

Comment: Can u help me how the "comparator" would be in my case?

Comment: You should put the `maps` list after the definition of the maps it contains. The example will not compile as is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create your own custom sort comparator like this in Groovy:

```
maps.sort { a, b -> a.key3 <=> b.key3 }
```

This will sort the maps based on the value of each one's `key3`.

Comment: What do `a` and `b` represent?

Comment: The closure here is like a Comparator, and `a` and `b` are two list elements to be compared for the sort operation. Since `maps` is a List of Map objects, `a` and `b` are each Maps in this case. See the docs here: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#sort(groovy.lang.Closure)

Answer (score 2):

You can deal with the ArrayList of maps like with any other ArrayList. Hence calling the [Collections.sort(List)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) would take care of your issue, sorting it using the natural order of hashMaps - probably this will use identity. In case you want to provide a Comparator to provide more appropriate logic to what you have in mind you can use [Collections.sort(List, Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)).

In groovy you can call directly the `.sort()` on a given array, this is possible as the [DefaultGroovyMethods](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html) contains several helper methods, among with several sorting related methods.

On your code:

```
def map1 = [key1:"1",key2:"2",key3:"3"]
def map2 = [key1:"2",key2:"3",key3:"1"]
def map3 = [key1:"3",key2:"1",key3:"2"]
def maps = [map1,map2,map3 ]


maps.sort();
maps.sort({m1, m2 -> m1.key3 <=> m2.key3})

println maps
```

**Output:**

```
[[key1:2, key2:3, key3:1], [key1:3, key2:1, key3:2], [key1:1, key2:2, key3:3]]
```

This response are based on capabilities of groovy 2.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

I put some values, to make easier to understand...

You can create a comparison block (very analogous to a Comparator) and pass it to the sort() method

```
def map1 = [key1:11,key2:12,key3:13] 
def map2 = [key1:21,key2:22,key3:23] 
def map3 = [key1:31,key2:32,key3:33]
def maps = [map2,map1,map3]  //map1 in second position

maps.sort({mapa, mapb -> mapa.key3.compareTo(mapb.key3)})​
```

Would yield

```
[[key1:11, key2:12, key3:13], [key1:21, key2:22, key3:23], [key1:31, key2:32, key3:33]] //now they are sorted
```